# Modifying stored procedure to add new column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, group-by

First time poster, so I apologize if I'm not following all proper protocols.

I'm new to using SQL and MS report writer. I know just enough to get in trouble. Pulling some data from scratch is so much easier than modifying the reports from the stored procedures that are already built for our database.

I'm trying to modify a report to add a column for Order Type. I know that table `OrderType o` contains o.OrderTypeId and o.OrderType (description). The `txnsroot t` contains the t.OrderTypeId, but everything I'm trying keeps giving me an error

> "Column 'OrderType.OrderType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I just want a column to display the OrderType descriptions as text.

Here's the original query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @BranchName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @groupby VARCHAR(255)

set @StartDate = '11/20/2023'
set @EndDate ='12/03/2023'
set @BranchName = 'Some branch id'
set @groupby = 'Branch'

    DECLARE @pStartDate SMALLDATETIME ,
        @pEndDate SMALLDATETIME ,
        @ConfigValue VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT  @pStartDate = DATEADD(dd, -14, @StartDate) , 
            @pEndDate = DATEADD(dd, -1, @StartDate);     

Select MAX (a.itemid) as ItemId, t.aident
into #TempActive
From txnsroot t
INNER JOIN Assignmentroot a on a.itemid=t.itemid
where a.activestatus=1
group by t.aident

    DECLARE @temp AS TABLE
        (
          BranchName VARCHAR(25) ,
          AIdent BIGINT PRIMARY KEY ,
          SSN VARCHAR(25) ,
          FormattedSSN VARCHAR(25) ,
          LastName VARCHAR(50) ,
          FirstName VARCHAR(50) ,
          Initial VARCHAR(5) ,
          Address VARCHAR(50) ,
          City VARCHAR(50) ,
          Zip VARCHAR(15) ,
          State VARCHAR(5) ,
          EmployeeDOB SMALLDATETIME ,
          TaxState VARCHAR(5) ,
          EmpStartDate SMALLDATETIME ,
          pStartDate SMALLDATETIME ,
          pEndDate SMALLDATETIME ,
          Grouplabel VARCHAR(50),
          ActiveStatus INT
        );
            
    WITH    AidentsPaidInDateRange ( aident, taxstate, weekenddate, txnid )
              AS ( SELECT   e.AIdent ,
                            e.TaxState ,
                            MIN(t.WeekendDate) ,
                            t.TxnId
                   FROM     Employeeroot e
                            INNER JOIN TxnsRoot t WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON e.AIdent = t.AIdent
                                                              AND t.WeekendDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                            LEFT JOIN TxnsRoot t2 WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON e.AIdent = t2.AIdent
                                                              AND t2.WeekendDate BETWEEN @pStartDate AND @pEndDate
                            INNER JOIN AssignmentRoot a WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON t.ItemID = a.ItemID
                   WHERE    t2.AIdent IS NULL
                            AND a.W2 = 1
                            AND e.TaxState IS NOT NULL
                            AND t.ChkId IS NOT NULL 
                   GROUP BY e.AIdent ,
                            t.TxnId ,
                            e.TaxState
                 ),
            AIdentsNeedingNewHireReporting ( aident, startdate )
              AS ( SELECT   apidr.aident ,
                            CASE WHEN ( apidr.taxstate = 'AL' )
                                      OR ( apidr.taxstate = 'MN' )
                                 THEN CASE WHEN t.Day7 > 0 THEN t.WeekendDate
                                           WHEN t.Day6 > 0
                                           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, t.WeekendDate)
                                           WHEN t.Day5 > 0
                                           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, t.WeekendDate)
                                           WHEN t.Day4 > 0
                                           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, t.WeekendDate)
                                           WHEN t.Day3 > 0
                                           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -4, t.WeekendDate)
                                           WHEN t.Day2 > 0
                                           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -5, t.WeekendDate)
                                           WHEN t.Day1 > 0
                                           THEN DATEADD(DAY, -6, t.WeekendDate)
                                           ELSE t.PeriodStartDate
                                      END
                                 ELSE apidr.weekenddate
                            END
                   FROM     AidentsPaidInDateRange apidr
                            INNER JOIN TxnsRoot (NOLOCK) t ON apidr.txnid = t.TxnId
                 )

    INSERT  INTO @temp
            ( BranchName ,
              AIdent ,
              SSN ,
              FormattedSSN ,
              LastName ,
              FirstName ,
              Initial ,
              Address ,
              City ,
              Zip ,
              State ,
              EmployeeDOB ,
              TaxState ,
              EmpStartDate ,
              pStartDate ,
              pEndDate ,
              Grouplabel,
              ActiveStatus
            )
            SELECT  b.BranchName ,
                    e.AIdent ,
                    e.SSN ,
                    dbo.FormatSSN(e.SSN) AS FormattedSSN ,
                    e.LastName ,
                    e.FirstName ,
                    UPPER(LEFT(e.Initial, 1)) AS Initial ,
                    e.Address ,
                    e.City ,
                    e.Zip ,
                    e.State ,
                    eeo.EmployeeDOB ,
                    e.TaxState ,
                    MIN(annhr.startdate) AS EmpStartDate ,    
                    @pStartDate AS pStartDate ,
                    @pEndDate AS pEndDate ,
                    '',
                    Case when t.itemid is Null then 0 else 1 end
            FROM    Employeeroot e 
                    LEFT JOIN EmployeeEEO eeo WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON e.AIdent = eeo.AIdent
                    INNER JOIN BranchRoot b WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON b.BranchId = e.BranchId
                    INNER JOIN AIdentsNeedingNewHireReporting annhr ON annhr.aident = e.AIdent 
                    LEFT JOIN #TempActive t on t.aident=e.aident
  
            GROUP BY b.BranchName ,
                    e.AIdent ,
                    e.SSN ,
                    e.LastName ,
                    e.FirstName ,
                    e.Initial ,
                    e.Address ,
                    e.City ,
                    e.Zip ,
                    e.State ,
                    eeo.EmployeeDOB ,
                    e.TaxState ,
                    t.itemid
            ORDER BY LastName ,
                    FirstName;
                                          

    UPDATE  @temp
    SET     SSN = dbo.FormatSSN(SSN)
                                                    
    IF @groupby = 'Branch'
        UPDATE  @temp
        SET     Grouplabel = BranchName;

    IF @groupby = 'Tax State'
        UPDATE  @temp
        SET     Grouplabel = TaxState;

    IF @groupby = 'Start Date'
        UPDATE  @temp
        SET     Grouplabel = CONVERT(VARCHAR, EmpStartDate, 101);


    SELECT  *,
            '' AS ReportHeaderBranchList
    FROM    @temp
    ORDER BY Grouplabel ,
            EmpStartDate ,
            LastName ,
            FirstName;
```

This is what I thought I needed to change:

```
Select MAX (a.itemid) as ItemId, t.aident,**o.ordertype**
into #TempActive
From txnsroot t
INNER JOIN Assignmentroot a on a.itemid=t.itemid
**INNER JOIN OrderType o on o.ordertypeid=t.ordertypeid**
where a.activestatus=1
group by t.aident
```

```
INSERT INTO @temp
  (
...ActiveStatus,
   OrderType
  )
SELECT ...
  o.ordertype

GROUP BY ...
  o.ordertype
```

Comment: When you use SQL aggregation (in most of RDBMs) everything you have in `SELECT` clause should be either an aggregation function or a field that is included in `GROUP BY`.  And this is exactly what the error message tells you.